# Firestore collection querying on map field

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I've a firestore collection like below and I would like to query on Map field to filter the results. Here is my code but I always see  no result. Could someone help here? thank you!

```
const myRef = firebase.firestore().collection('otherCollection').doc('123456');
const res = await firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('myCollection')
  .where('testMap.array1', 'in ',  myRef)
  .get();
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to rewrite "where" part as `where("testMap.array1", "array-contains", myRef)`?

Comment: Sounds like an answer @MedvedievV. :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not a JS developer and didn't check if my suggestion actually works. If you've checked it, feel free to post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is known as an `array-contains` operation in Firestore. It is implement as:

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('myCollection')
  .where('testMap.array1', 'array-contains',  myRef)
  .get();
```

I've never run an `array-contains` with a document reference myself, so let me know if it works or not.